# JMeter 5.0 - Skip current iteration from pre-processor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

My requirement is to ALWAYS validate the input test data before firing the main sampler with that. Given that, I am using throughput shaping timer, I do not want to process the input in another sampler before passing it to the main sampler inside an IF controller. (Since the input processing sampler gets counted against the throughput)

I am trying to set TestLogicalAction programmatically inside a pre-processor for this.

The below line is working properly if I use it inside an assertion.

SampleResult.setTestLogicalAction(TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);

But a variant of the same line is NOT working inside a pre-processor

**Attempt1:**

ctx.getPreviousResult().setTestLogicalAction(TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);

**Attemp2:**

ctx.setTestLogicalAction(TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);

Both the attempts are not throwing any errors. But they are not skipping the sampler execution after the pre-processor. How can I achieve this inside a pre-processor?